# Trouble Merging Two Data Frames With NA

Tags: r, merge

For the following code, I'm expecting an 8 by 3 data frame with the "a" column being the common column on the left.  Instead, I'm getting a 32 by 3 data frame.  This works for me when I use dates as a common column, but not now.  Any thoughts?

```
a <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
b <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,6,7,8)
c <- c(NA,NA,NA,4,5,6,7,8)
d1 <- data.frame(a,b)
d2 <- data.frame(a,c)
d3 <- merge(d1,d2,by=c("a"))
```

EDIT:  Guidance from [AM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/ananda-mahto) led me to search for merging dataframes with cbind and the solution was as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344414/r-programming-combining-two-data-frames).

Comment: Are you really looking for `merge` or just for `cbind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output you describe, it sounds like you want `cbind` rather than `merge`. Try the following:

```
cbind(d1, d2[-1])
#   a  b  c
# 1 A  1 NA
# 2 A  2 NA
# 3 A  3 NA
# 4 A NA  4
# 5 B NA  5
# 6 B  6  6
# 7 B  7  7
# 8 B  8  8
```